# Read Text Label by Length VB.net

Tags: vb.net, label

i have `Label1`' with text in that = `10500` and `Label2` , 
and if my `Label1.Text.Length = 5` my `Label2.Text = Label1.Text.Length=3`    (i want Label2 text is 5 because number 5 is label text length 3, but if i use this code :

```
 Label1.Text = "10500"
 If Homepage.Label1.Text.Length = 5 Then
          Homepage.Label2.Text = Homepage.Label1.Text.Length = 3
 End If
```

Label2 only show code "False"
I want my label2 show to code for label1.text in length 3, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning label2  a Boolean

```
Label1.Text = "10500"
 If Homepage.Label1.Text.Length = 5 Then
          Homepage.Label2.Text = Homepage.Label1.Text.Length = 3
 End If
```

This part is wrong:
   Homepage.Label2.Text = **Homepage.Label1.Text.Length = 3**

Homepage.Label1.Text.Length = 3 evaluates to False or True

If I understood you right, you need to do something like this

```
    Label1.Text = "10500"
     If Homepage.Label1.Text.Length = 5 Then
       If Homepage.Label1.Text.Length = 3 Then
              Homepage.Label2.Text = Homepage.Label1.Text.Substring(3, 1)
       End if
     End If
```

Comment: I Only want text in length 3, ex : 10500 i only want text "5", ex : 12345 i only want text "3" , can you elp me?

Comment: Aha I edited the answer for you , you should use substring to pick a letter in a string

Comment: Thank you sir !, but can you help me what is (3, 1) in Substring ? Thank you before !

Comment: it is , substring(positionInString. lengthToCut)